# Seeking advice for "dual mode" for increment/decrement of control with UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I implemented a custom iOS control (looking similar to a ruler), where the user can easily scroll to select one of about 300 values.

My control also has the trait `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable` and implements the methods `accessibilityIncrement()` and `accessibilityDecrement()` of the protocol `UIAccessibilityAction` to update its value. So far everything works as intended.

The problem is that adjusting the value via VoiceOver can be tedious, since each swipe gesture increments/decrements the value only by one. Is there a good way to offer a second mode where the updates happen, e.g. in steps of ten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable` uses a fixed, developer-defined increment size. You can adjust the slider with a larger step size in `-accessibilityIncrement` if you think users will find it tedious to adjust the control one unit at a time. VoiceOver users desiring finer control can use the pass-through gesture (double tap and hold) to interact with the control directly, sliding to adjust it in single-percent increments. This does, however, assume users have fine motor control.

If you feel strongly that `UIAccessibility` should support a "fine-grain" adjustment mode, [file an enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com) with supporting use cases.

Comment: Thanks. I settled with the following approach: increments via the adjustable-methods remain at single steps (precision is mandatory). For larger update steps the user can swipe upwards/downwards with three fingers instead of one. iOS provides these events as upwards/downwards scroll intends in the method `accessibilitySCroll:`. From my point of view it seems quite natural.

Comment: That's quite creative, kudos for the idea. Put another way, though, it's inconsistent and potentially undiscoverable. Without access to the scroll gesture, or the "donk" indicating that the content is done scrolling, how will VoiceOver users exploring your interface realize that the content _isn't_ scrollable?